# How to use li and ul tag in JSF Framework?

Tags: jsf

How to use  li and ul tag in JSF Framework?

Comment: without verbatium how to use li and ul..

Answer (score 14):

You can use standard html mixed with JSF syntax. Just write

```
<ul>
<li> Apple </li>
<li> Banana </li>
</ul>
```

I guess what you want is displaying a list from a `List`

If you are using Facelets, do:

```
<ul>
<ui:repeat value="#{myBean.items}" var="item">
<li><h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/></li>
</ui:repeat>
</ul>
```

If you are not, you should. Anyway, you can do the same with the old JSTL and `c:forEach`

```
<html ... xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">
...
<ul>
<c:forEach items="#{myBean.items}" var="item">
<li><h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/></li>
</c:forEach>
</ul>
```

Comment: Pakore 

Inside <li> can i use commandlink?
is verbatium needed?

Comment: inside <li> you can use any JSF tag you want.

Comment: @Hari: `f:verbatim` is only needed if you're using the vintage JSF 1.1. Since JSF 1.2 the view handler has been improved to automatically do that. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844843/is-there-any-problem-when-i-mix-jsf-with-plain-html).

Comment: If you're using JSF 1.1 with Facelets, f:verbatim would be optional, too.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Tomahawk's `t:dataList`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk12/tagdoc/t_dataList.html) to render a `<ul><li>` in a "jsfish" way without bringing in "plain vanilla" HTML. Useful if you're still on JSF 1.0/1.1 yet and don't want to hassle with `f:verbatim`.

```
<t:dataList layout="unorderedList" value="#{bean.list}" var="item">
    <h:outputText value="#{item}" />
</t:dataList>
```

which generates

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

which look like this

- item 1
- item 2
- item 3

Comment: I guess the "if you're still on jsf 1.0 / 1.1 is the point - or is there a reason to avoid plain vanilla html in JSF 1.2 / 2.X ?

Comment: @Toskan: No, you can't use plain vanilla HTML in JSF 1.0/1.1. See also  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3646940 for a bit of history.

Comment: Actually, you can successfully use plain vanilla HTML in JSF 1.1 (I'm not sure about 1.0), as long as you use it with Facelets.