# JSF refreshing list via Ajax incorrectly

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I am trying to migrate some functionality from JQuery to JSF and I am getting strange results.

Basically it is a page where you can navigate links (imagine like a Windows Explorer on the Web). Folders have a link and leafs don't. To construct this, it is used a `private List<Element> list;`, which is refreshed accordingly. So when the user clicks on a "folder", a new `list` is created with the contents of that folder.

The problem is that I am getting strange results. Sometimes I navigate a link and it is refreshed correctly, but in some cases it behaves like the page is reloaded (but it is not) and the `list` is reset to its initial values (?). For example, I navigate to "name2" and get the right things. But then I go to "name2b" and I instead of the leafs I get "name1", "name2" and "name3", which are only set in the `init()` method. I don't know how this happens, but exploring the source code it seems that the `c:foreach` structure is messing with the ids and an old ID is rendered in the page (note that I have tried `ui:repeat` with same incorrect results).

How can I fix this?

This is the simplified code:

```
<f:metadata>
   <f:viewAction action="#{controller.init}" />
</f:metadata>
...
<h:panelGroup id="visor" layout="block">
            <ul>
                <c:forEach items="#{controller.list}" var="element">
                    <li>
                        <ui:fragment rendered="#{element.folder}">
                            <h:form>
                                <h:commandButton action="#{controller.navigate(element.name)}" type="submit" value="#{element.name}" >
                                    <f:ajax render="visor" execute="@this" />
                                </h:commandButton>
                            </h:form>
                        </ui:fragment>
                        <ui:fragment rendered="#{not element.folder}">
                            <span>#{element.name}</span>
                        </ui:fragment>
                    </li>
                </c:forEach>
            </ul>
        </h:panelGroup>
```

And the controller

```
@Named(value = "controller")
@ViewScoped
public class MyController implements Serializable {

private List<Element> list;

public void init() { //Called when loading the page
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    Element e1 = new Element("name1", true); //name and isFolder?
    Element e2 = new Element("name2", true);
    Element e3 = new Element("name3", true);
    list.add(e1);
    list.add(e2);
    list.add(e3);
}

public void navigate(String name) {
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    if (name.equals("name1")) {
         Element e1 = new Element("name1a", true);
         Element e2 = new Element("name1b", true);
         Element e3 = new Element("name1c", true);
         list.add(e1); list.add(e2); list.add(e3);
    } else if (name.equals("name2")) {
        Element e1 = new Element("name2a", true);
         Element e2 = new Element("name2b", true);
         Element e3 = new Element("name2c", true);
         list.add(e1); list.add(e2); list.add(e3);
    } else {
        Element e1 = new Element("leaf1", false);
         Element e2 = new Element("leaf2", false);
         list.add(e1); list.add(e2);
    }
}
//....
```

---

**EDIT**

My problem seems to be described [in here](https://drewdev.blogspot.com/2008/08/cforeach-with-jsf-could-ruin-your-day.html).

I have to investigate if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31963015/jsf-dynamic-add-remove-components-in-cforeach-loop) can bring some light to the subject.

Comment: Start by **not** doing `type="submit"` on the commandbutton. And how and when is the init called? Should it not just be a `@PostConstruct` annotated method. Please try to create a [mcve]  instead of having us guess. Oh and check http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/tree, might be very intersting And **debug**... check if things are unexpectedly called...

Comment: What is the reason for not `submit`? I have done this in other places and it always worked fine. I will update for the init(). I have also debugged and the calls are all correct and the size() of the list too. But when I get the error, there is no call to "navigate()"

Comment: 1: it is the 'default', 2: In combination with ajax I've sometimes seen strange things (jsf <2.2 but never the less).. Oh now I noticed you use ajax and (think) update the page with the `c:foreach`. That won't work. You cannot update a part that is rendered via c:foreach... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense (read all >25 upvote Q/A on JSF and remember their existence for the future.... really helpful. Or start at http://jsf.zeef.com

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I read that post in the past and it makes sense, although I tried `ui:repeat` too unsuccessfully as I said in the question. So how can I update the page section of a group of elements printed by a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is a [well-known thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31963015/jsf-dynamic-add-remove-components-in-cforeach-loop#comment51833956_31963015) that my structure cannot be dynamically updated in JSF. The solution I have to make is to use a `h:datatable` instead of a `<ul>` list (this is one thing I really dislike of JSF, but I am not sure how to [render a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3236666/1156544) with basic JSF - instead of a table, that I can dynamically update.

The Ajax `render` attribute had to specify the `form` id.

```
<h:form id="visor">
      <h:dataTable value="#{controller.list}" var="element">
                    <h:column>
                        ....
                        <h:commandButton action=.... >
                          <f:ajax render="visor" execute="@this" />
                        </h:commandButton>
                        ....
                    </h:column>
      </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

**Edit**: The `UL` also worked, as long as I render the form and the form contains everything

Comment: I use a ui:repeat for similar things (iirc), not sure why it does not work for you. Will try and see what makes this case actually not work...  In the 'well-known-thing' post, you see that the poster uses `c:for-each` and that it is suggested to use a `ui:repeat` as an outer loop... So I'll check tonight...

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure if the problem was where the `form` was located, and which id was used for the `render`. I also need to create a structure like: `<nav> <ul> <li><a ...></a></li> </ul> </nav>` and I cannot use a `datatable` for that. So I have tried a list and `ui:repeat` and it seems to work in that place - so I am confused. I will do some more testing